# How to remove words from one column by comparing another column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, keyword

I am trying to automatically generate keywords by using some machine learning algorithm. In that process, on the outcome I also see some unwanted keywords are also generated, and now I need to remove that unwanted/redundant words from the output column algorithmically. [unwanted keywords are nothing but, words that are not existing in the input column but still generated in the output column]
Below is an example, I am trying to generate keywords by referring "query_text" column. The results are store in "auto generated keywords" column. But you see there are few keywords that are extracted unnecessarily ('diamond' and 'ring') and I highlighted the same in red color (in row 1 and row 3 respectively). Now in the final (corrected keywords) column, I have given only the necessary words.

How can I do this algorithmically by comparing the results (auto generated keywords) and the input (query_text).

```
 S.No                      query_text auto generated keywords corrected keywords
    1                     I want ring            diamond|ring               ring
    2             I want wedding band            band|wedding       band|wedding
    3  I look for sapphire collection           ring|sapphire           sapphire
    4          I want diamond earring         diamond|earring    diamond|earring
    5 I am looking for stackable ring          ring|stackable     ring|stackable
    6            I need gold bracelet           bracelet|gold      bracelet|gold
    7            I look for gold ring               gold|ring          gold|ring
    8            I need sapphire ring           ring|sapphire      ring|sapphire
```

Data with higlighted extra words:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a list comprehension on pairs of `query`/`auto generated words` ([`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)), with a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) for efficient membership test:

```
df['corrected keywords'] = ['|'.join(w for w in l if w in S)
                            for S, l in zip(df['query_text'].apply(lambda x: set(x.split())),
                                            df['auto generated keywords'].str.split('|'))]
```

Output:

```
   S.No                       query_text auto generated keywords corrected keywords
0     1                      I want ring            diamond|ring               ring
1     2              I want wedding band            band|wedding       band|wedding
2     3   I look for sapphire collection           ring|sapphire           sapphire
3     4           I want diamond earring         diamond|earring    diamond|earring
4     5  I am looking for stackable ring          ring|stackable     ring|stackable
5     6             I need gold bracelet           bracelet|gold      bracelet|gold
6     7             I look for gold ring               gold|ring          gold|ring
7     8             I need sapphire ring           ring|sapphire      ring|sapphire
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a less elegant solution to the problem.

I first cleaned each line of auto generated keywords by removing the | and the spaces in between and converted them into a list with the use of a function.

```
def stripdown(column):
    for index in range(1,len(column)+1):
        return_list = []
        raw_string = column[index]
        split_string = raw_string.split('|')
        for text in split_string:
            return_list.append(text.strip())
        column[index] = return_list
```

I then checked whether each word from auto generated key words is in query_text.

```
for index in range(1,len(new_df['auto generated keywords'])+1):
    for item in new_df['auto generated keywords'][index]:
        if item not in new_df['query_text'][index]:
            new_df['auto generated keywords'][index].remove(item)
        else:
            continue
```

This is the [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi8HQ.jpg)